# Change in a joint account

Tags: india, bank-account, joint-account

My father and my mother are joint owners of a saving account in Punjab national bank Jalandhar Punjab. Now they want to change the nominee of the account. Do both of these joint owners require to visit the branch personally to change the nominee of the account or one joint holder himself can do so by visiting the branch alone.

Comment: In the US, it would depend on whether it is an *and* joint account or an *or* joint account.

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you phone the bank and you tell them the type of the account, they will tell you.

Comment: @SJuan76 The account is in India where there is _no_ correlation between what the bank will say on the phone (if it answers the phone at all) and whose presence will actually be required when someone actually goes to the bank to make the desired change. Also, in practice if not in law, the account is presumed to be the sole property of the first-named owner and so if the first name is the mother's and the father goes to make the change, he will likely be rebuffed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check with the Bank to determine if the account is "Either - or- survivor" which means that either party can make any change to the account.
If the account was created with one party being under-18 then some additional restrictions apply. Your best bet is to contact the home branch.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend upon the bank policy. Generally bank would need the nomination from filled and signed by both. The form can be submitted by any one.